# check if dataframe contains empty values for certain columns based on a predefined condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I created a dataframe with columns 'City', 'Address', 'Address1' and 'Postcode' with some values. However, some of them are empty so I would like to label them as **'n'** as they require further work to collect the data.

My code below is trying to say that when City = london, it *must not have* empty values for 'City', 'Address' and 'Postcode'. In addition, when City != london, it must not have empty values for all of **'City', 'Address', 'Address1' and 'Postcode'.** Otherwise, create a new column called 'Label' and put 'n' as the value at the index of where the conditions have failed.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
        'City': ['london', 'manchester', 'liverpool', 'birmingham'],
        'Address': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
        'Address1': ['E', 'F', '', 'H'],
        'Postcode': ['', '', 'L1 0AA', 'B23 3AW ']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


if ((df['City']).any() == 'london'):
    df['City'].empty == False
    df['Address'].empty == False
    df['Postcode'].empty == False

elif ((df['City']).any() != 'london'):
    df['City'].empty == False
    df['Address'].empty == False
    df['Address1'].empty == False
    df['Postcode'].empty == False    
else:
    df.insert(2, "Label", 'n' )#here, I need to change the code to insert 'n' to the specific index at column 'Label' where the conditions are not true
    print('This record is missing data')
print(df)
```

Here is the output of above code.

```
         City Address Address1  Postcode
0      london       A        E          
1  manchester       B        F          
2   liverpool       C             L1 0AA
3  birmingham       D        H  B23 3AW
```

This is what I'm trying to get:

```
         City Address Address1  Postcode  Label
0      london       A        E              n
1  manchester       B        F              n
2   liverpool       C             L1 0AA    n
3  birmingham       D        H  B23 3AW
```

The only correct record is 'birmingham' because it's meeting the 'elif' condition, therefore it does need an 'n' label.

Any helps are appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
out = df.replace('',np.nan)

nulls = out[['Address','Address1','Postcode']].isna()
c = (out['City'].eq('london') & nulls[['Address','Postcode']].any(1)|
                                                        nulls.any(1))
df['Label'] = np.where(c,'n','')
```

---

```
print(df)

         City Address Address1  Postcode Label
0      london       A        E               n
1  manchester       B        F               n
2   liverpool       C             L1 0AA     n
3  birmingham       D        H  B23 3AW
```